# Truecypt: Write / Access / Read / to outer volume while hidden operating system is running

Tags: windows, truecrypt

First time poster, looooong time reader. I feel like I've searched high and low to no avail, so here goes:

If one were to have both a decoy OS and a hidden OS, and they wanted to access (ie mount and read / write) the outer volume from the hidden OS while it's running, is this possible?

I simply cannot do it, and am thinking it is a precautionary measure, though the FAQs at the site and other forums don't seem to mention it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. you cannot mount both volumes at once. See the bottom paragraph of this page to see why: http://www.truecrypt.org/hiddenvolume

> When mounting an outer volume, the user can enter two passwords: One for the outer volume, and the other for a hidden volume within it, which he wants to protect. **In this mode, TrueCrypt does not actually mount the hidden volume.** It only decrypts its header and retrieves information about the size of the hidden volume (from the decrypted header). Then, the outer volume is mounted and any attempt to save data to the area of the hidden volume will be rejected (until the outer volume is dismounted).

it is also problematic to write to the outer volume at all, but you can do it, if you enable protection for the inner volume. see more info here:
http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/hidden-volume-protection

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I *did* read that but I understood it differently. Thank you for your response, Frank! :)